# creating an algorithm to find repeating values of an array

Tags: algorithm

I made a pseudo code algorithm to find repeating values of an array which includes float numbers:

```
mergeSort(A);  
int i <- 0
for i<- A.lenght-1
  if Arr[i] == A[i+1]
          return A[i]
          while A[i] = A[i+1]
                i++
else
    i++
```

I want to change the above algorithm to find the repeating values and the number of times they repeat. I have created the following algorithm:

```
mergeSort(A); 
HashMap hashMap;
Int result <-0 int i <- 0
for i<- A.lenght-1
    int j <- 0
    if A[i] == A[i+1]
          j <- j+1
          result <- A[i]
          while A[i] == A[i+1]
             i <- i+1
             j<- j+1
         hashMap.insert(result , j)
      else
         i++
return hashMap
```

Is this an efficient algorithm?  Is it a good way to use a hashmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `HashMap` and do something like this:

```java
HashMap hash;
for (int i = 0; i < A.lenght; i++){
    value = hash.get(A[i]); 
    if (value == null) // is the first time that we find A[i]
        hash.put(A[i], 1);
    else    // A[i] is a duplicate
        hash.put(A[i], value + 1);
}
```

avarage case = `O(n)`

I agree with pboulanger: pay attention to floating-point comparison.

Comment: thats great, thanks. but, does hashmap accept float as a key? isnt there ant constraint for hashmap only to accept integers as keys?

Comment: does data structure HashTable has the method get(key)- that you have use above - too?

Comment: Sandra you can use float, but you have to use wrapper class. Here are all methods supported http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html . Anywhere if you know how HashMap works, you can implement your own HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the floating-point numbers are not exact types and the equal operator could return wrong values. For floating-point values prefer a test |f1-f2|

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to store the result in an `ArrayList` of `[value count]` pairs, this is probably slightly more effective, there's really no need for a `HashMap` here. I know practially nothing about java, but you should be able to write something like:

```
arrayList.add(new Pair(result, j));
```

Comment: How can I insert pairs into ArrayList? arrayList arr;

Comment: how about an HashTable? Isnt it better that I use it?

Comment: A hashmap is useful when you need to do fast lookups in a table with "random" indices. What you're doing here is inserting numbers in a well defined order so there's really no need for a hash map.

Comment: does it differ if I want to find duplicate i an array which includes integer numbers? should I use arayList for integers too?

Comment: @Andreas Brinck, Array List is not efficient in all, It's better to use list or array or other generic collections not array list.

Comment: @Saeed As I said I know little of **java** but I think that the size of an `Array` must be known at creation which makes it unusable for this task. As for `List`, I thought it was just an interface which is implemented by for instance `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, of those two I would guess `ArrayList` is more efficient in this application than `LinkedList`, or do you have other information?